# Fastest way to search array for a string that contains variable

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array sample:

```
array(3) { 
[0]=> string(20) "1845-260-phone-nokia"
[1]=> string(22) "1133-0-phone-motorola" 
[2]=> string(20) "1133-0-phone-samsung" 
}
```

My goal is to search the array and to find if the string exists in the array.

Let me first explain what this string means:

```
"1845-260-phone-nokia"
```

1845 - product id
260 - this is variable and it is unknown
phone - is product make
nokia is product model
All is known excluding the variable..

How can I search the array so if I have:

```
[0]=> string(20) "18451-260-phone-nokia"
```

to be recognized as different product
I hope you will undestand what I mean. Till now I used in_array but after recently added variable in the string this doesnt work..
Thank you for helping me !

Comment: for example, try with the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php

Comment: Do you want to search for the whole string or just some part of it?

Comment: array-search will search for exact string  in my question I dont know what it would be because of the variable..

Comment: array_search() is looking for an exact match.... but using [array_filter()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with a callback using [fnmatch()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fnmatch.php) or even simply [strpos()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) should work

Comment: Do u want to search the whole string for the product id and display the corresponding product?

Comment: if I search the whole string the chances to find correct result are greater otherwise it may return true for similar string..

Comment: What I meant was. Do you want to search for exact match such as `'1845-260-phone-nokia' == '1845-260-phone-nokia'` or do you want to check if `260` in the string?

Comment: sorry, missunderstood the question

Comment: AnotherGuy - I want to find if the exact match except the variable 260 - so exact match but ignoring the variable value.

Comment: Mark can you please provide sample code of your solution?

Comment: If I have understood you correctly you would like to match like the following: `1845-(something)-phone-nokia`?

Comment: AnotherGuy - exactly ! :)

Comment: Then I think the easiest way is using a regular expression. This both have an advantage and a disadvantage. You can easily capture the unknown number, while sacrificing some performance though. You could do some nifty string manipulation, but my guess is that it would take just as much time as a regular expression and make readability harder.

Comment: ok, than is it another way that can guarantee that search will find the exact product id - first string between -1845-, but not 18451 and without exploding?

Comment: If you only need to match against the first number sequence it can be done quite fast. If that is what you want let me know.

Comment: guys some emergency came up and I must go out for an hour.. Thank you and sorry for leaving you !

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php strongly recommed you to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While trying to fulfill your wish that no `explode()` function calls are used, I have created two functions that can match using the model number and the manufacturer. The first function matches using a regular expression, while the second using string manipulation. Performance wise I have no idea. They could properly both be optimized A LOT, but the functionality should be there.

The regular expression version has the advantage that it captures the unknown number. This can easily be refactored away if you do not want that functionality. But my guess is that it is somehow important. If not, then why store it in the first place :D

```
/**
 * Finds the first matching phone using a regular expression.
 *
 * @param array  $phones        An array of available phones
 * @param string $model         The model number of the phone
 * @param string $manufacturer  The manufacturer of the phone
 *
 * @return array|bool Returns an associative array with matched phone and the
 *                    unknown number on success. Returns FALSE if no match.
 */
function find_phone_regex(array $phones, $model, $manufacturer) {

    /*
     * OPS: I have added the 'i' flag to make it case-insensitive.
     * This might not be the wished behavior.
     */
    $regex = '~^' . $model . '-(?<number>[0-9]+)-phone-' . $manufacturer . '$~i';

    foreach($phones as $phone) {

        if(preg_match($regex, $phone, $matches)) {

            return [
                'phone'  => $phone,
                'number' => $matches['number']
            ];

        }
    }

    return false;
}

/**
 * Finds the first matching phone.
 *
 * @param array  $phones        An array of available phones
 * @param string $model         The model number of the phone
 * @param string $manufacturer  The manufacturer of the phone
 *
 * @return string|bool Returns the phone on success. Returns FALSE if it does not exist.
 */
function find_phone_string(array $phones, $model, $manufacturer) {

    $input_model_pos        = strlen($model);
    $input_manufacturer_pos = strlen($manufacturer);

    $model        = strtolower($model);
    $manufacturer = strtolower($manufacturer);

    foreach($phones as $phone) {

        $phone_model        = substr($phone, 0, $input_model_pos);
        $phone_manufacturer = substr($phone, -$input_manufacturer_pos);

        if(strtolower($phone_model) == $model && strtolower($phone_manufacturer) == $manufacturer) {
            return $phone;
        }

    }

    return false;

}
```

The usage for both of them are the same regarding the argument list. Only the function name is different. Using the data you have provided the two function will return the following (displayed with `var_dump()`).

The regular expression version.

```
$phone = find_phone_regex($phones, '1845', 'nokia');

array (size=2)
  'phone' => string '1845-260-phone-nokia' (length=20)
  'number' => string '260' (length=3)
```

The string version.

```
$phone = find_phone_string($phones, '1845', 'nokia');

string '1845-260-phone-nokia' (length=20)
```

Comment: Thank you AnotherGuy, I slightly change it to make it work for my case , thank you !

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array("1845-260-phone-nokia", "1133-0-phone-motorola", "1133-0-phone-samsung");
$search = 'nokia';
$results found = array();
foreach ($array as $key => $value){

    if (strpos($value, $search) !== false)
     $results_found[] = $value; 

}
echo 'following results found: '.implode('<br>', $results_found);
```

Comment: The is by far the fastest solution, but there might be more phones from Nokia in the array. This would only find the first Nokia phone.